# Why does the Torah say כחטאת כאשם and not האשם כחטאת in Vayikro 7 (7)

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, korban, tzav

[Vayikro 7 (7)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9908) has the expression כַּחַטָּאת כָּאָשָׁם to mean that the אשם is like the  חַטָּאת.

The wording האשם כחטאת would seem to express this too and is used by Ramban on [Braishis 15 (9)](http://mobile.tora.ws/html/1-14.html).

Is there a special reason (an interpretation) why the basis of the comparison (the chatos) is mentioned before the thing to be compared (the oshom) or is this a normal idiom?

Comment: Not entirely sure. I looked at it as genus/species: the asham is part of the larger category of chatat. Homo sapiens

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky "Taxonomic-ally" speaking, Asham is probably closer to an Olah than to a Chattat.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that this is standard, as the translation of Onkelos, and simple Peshat is:

> כְּחַטָּתָא כֵּן אֲשָׁמָא
>
> As the Chattas is, so is the Asham (my very rough translation)

This only makes sense if we first mention that which we know (Chattas was already explained in 6:18), and afterwards extrapolate to the one we don't know (Asham, which we are learning about now).